# Making knnsearch fast when one argument remains constant

Tags: matlab, search, for-loop, knn, parfor

I have the following problem.

```
for i=1:3000
    [~,dist(i,1)]=knnsearch(C(selectedIndices,:),C);
end
```

Let me explain the code above. Matrix C is a huge matrix `(300000 x 1984)`. `C(selectedIndices,:)` is a subset of 100 elements of C depending on the value of `i`. It means: For `i=1`, first 100 points of C are selected, for `i==2`, `C(101:200,:)` is selected. As you can see, the second argument remains constant.

Is there any way to make this work faster. I have tried the following:

```
-  [~,dist(i,1)]=knnsearch(C,C); %obviously goes out of memory
```

- send a bigger chunk of `selectedIndices` instead of sending just 100. This adds a little bit post-processing which I am not worried about. But this doesn't work since it takes equivalent amount of time. For example, if I send 100 points of C at a time, it takes 60 seconds. If I send 500, it takes 380 seconds with the post-processing.
- Tried using `parfor` as: different sets of `selectedIndices` will be executed parallely.  It doesn't work as two copies of big matrix `C` may have got created (not sure how parfor works), but I am sure that computer becomes very slow in turn negating the advantage of parfor.
- Haven't tried yet: break both arguments into smaller chunks and send it in parfor. Do you think this will make any difference?

I am open to any suggestion i.e. if you feel braking a matrix in some different way may speed up the computation, do suggest it. Since, at the end I only care about finding closest point from a set of points (here each set has 100 points) for each point in C.

Comment: It takes 60 seconds to do the whole thing or one block of 100?

Comment: @BKay one block of 100, so in above code, it would take 3000 minutes to complete the code. I am looking to reduce the time to (lets say) 2000/2500 minutes

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have strong opinions on which rows are in the resulting matches. Is it essential that you use the Euclidean 2-norm? For example, if you can do principle component analysis on the data you may be able to reduce the dimensionality of the data substantially and therefore the speed of matching. Select the right number of factors with a Kaiser's stopping rule or eyeball the Scree Plot. The PCA step will be slow but I presume the resulting matches much faster.

Comment: @BKay what do you mean by "eyeball the screen plot"?

Comment: Not screen but scree. It graphs the principal components against the corresponding eigenvalues. Choosing the number optimally from the plot is a bit of an art but the Wikipedia page on principal components has a decent explanation. It depends on the problem, but in many real world situations the first 3 principal components explains 50-70% of the total variation of high dimensional problems. Because you have a 1984 dimensional problem, this makes matching a much lower dimensional problem, even if you need 10 factors.

Comment: If you could post a small subset of your data, say 1000 rows and all the columns, I might be able to show you what I mean.